# React Router v4 You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Using react-router-dom v4.3.1, I want to redirect from '/' to '/over/here' effectively redefining the root of the application. In ReactDOM.render() method:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/over/here" component={SomePlace} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/over/here" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Navigating directly to http://localhost/over/here renders SomePlace as expected - navigating to http://localhost/ throws this warning:

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on:
>   "/over/here"

This warning is also thrown if I use the "React-way-of-routing" in a component and render a `<Redirect to="some/other/place" />` on certain state conditions.

Finally, this also throws the warning:

```
<Router history={history}>
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/tutor/apply" component={TutorApplication} />
     <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/tutor/apply" />} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

What is going on here? I feel all the docs leave out the part of what happens after a new location is pushed into history (what the Redirect component is doing under the hood) - so what, how does pushing a new location get picked up by the router and render the correct component?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this, Shayno?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close the solution. You only have to place the `<Redirect />` above the `<Route />`.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect from="/" to="/over/here" />
    <Route exact path="/over/here" component={SomePlace} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```